# Error: maybe the else if statement?

Tags: c

It's been a while since I programmed anything in C so I need some help. The following code has an error of some sort. When I run the code the `if` and `else if` are skipped and my hardcoded error is prompted on the screen.

```
void play_tictactoe()
{
int row = 0, column = 0, i, win = 0;
char letter = 0;
char board[3][3] =
{
    {' ',' ',' '},
    {' ',' ',' '},
    {' ',' ',' '}
};

printf( "\nDo you want to be X or O: " );
scanf( "%c", &letter );

if( letter == 'x' || letter == 'X' )
{
    for( i = 0; i > 9 && win == 0; i++ )
    {
        printf( "\nPlace X: Row 1-3 and Column 1-3 (i.e. 1,3 for Row 1 and Column 3): " );
        scanf( "%i,%i", &row, &column );

        do
        {
            playersTurnX( &row, &column, board );
            computersTurnX( &row, &column, board );
        }
        while( row > 3 || column > 3);
    }
}
else if( letter == 'o' || letter == 'O' )
{
    for( i = 0; i > 9 && win == 0; i++ )
    {
        printf( "\nPlace O: Row 1-3 and Column 1-3 (i.e. 1,3 for Row 1 and Column 3): " );
        scanf( "%i,%i", &row, &column );

        do
        {
            //computersTurnO( &row, &column, &board );
            //playersTurnO( &row, &column, &board );
        }
        while( row > 3 || column > 3);
    }
}
else
{
    printf( "\nError!!!!\tInvalid entry.\n" );
}
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: amongst many other problems, from minor ones like the inconsistent indentation, to major ones like there is no way for the `win` variable to ever be updated nor any indication of the values of `win` when game end points like:  stalemate, O wins, or X wins  occurs.  Nor is there any way to repetitively display the board, after each move

Comment: when calling scanf() and family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when checking the user input for row and column, should verify the values are both in the range 1...3 and that the board[row][column] is not already taken.   Why would this kind of line: `while( row > 3 || column > 3);` ever be true, when the only allowed values for row and column are 1...3, so never greater than 3

Comment: the call to scanf() to obtain the row and column values says the format of the data entered by the user must be `#,#`.    That is a very restrictive format.  What if the user entered `# #`?  What if the user entered `# newline # newline`?

Comment: regarding this kind of line: `for( i = 0; i > 9 && win == 0; i++ )`  the first parameter set 'i' to 0 si 'i' will never be greater than 9 so the code jumps to the end of that 'for' loop .  similar considerations exist for other areas in the code.  Suggest: `for( i = 0; i < 9 && win == 0; i++ )`

Comment: debugging with something like 'gdb' would show that the interior of the 'for' loops are never being executed.

Answer (score 2):

When you use:

```
scanf( "%c", &letter );
```

you end up reading even newline characters into `c`. Use:

```
scanf( " %c", &letter );
//     ^^^^ add a space before %c.
```

Use of `" %c"` will make sure that all whitespace characters are skipped and only a non-whitespace character will be read into `c`.

Comment: Really, because I just tried it without space, and it reads exactly one character, no whitespace.

Comment: @BartFriederichs, try calling it twice. Then enter a character followed by Enter.

Comment: Right, the first time it works fine, second time not.

Comment: @BartFriederichs, exactly. The OP is running into the same issue.

Comment: the main problem with the OPs posted code has nothing to do with the calls to scanf() (although those calls could definitely use some improvements, especially in the area of error checking.)  The main problem(s) is the confusion the OP seems to have regarding the comparison operators. '<' and '>'

Comment: @user3629249, That may as well be another problem.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you want to add a space before the %c to eat up the white spaces:

```
scanf( " %c", &letter );
```

See there for more information: https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/caution-when-reading-char-with-scanf-c/